# Series convergence proof review (Baby Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Ch.3 #7. Prove that the convergence of $\sum a_n$ implies the convergence of $$\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n},$$ if $a_n \geq 0$.

> *My attempt.* If $\sum a_n$ is convergent, then by the root test, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} sup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} < 1$. This means $|a_n|^{1/n} < 1$. Because $a_n \geq 0$, this means $a_n ^{1/n} < 1$. Now apply the root test to $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ by considering $$\lim_{n \to \infty} sup \sqrt[n]{|\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}|}.$$ $$\sqrt[n]{|\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}|} = \frac{\sqrt{{a_n}^{\frac{1}{n}}}}{\sqrt[n]n}.$$ Because  $a_n ^{1/n} < 1$, certainly the numerator on the left-hand side of the equation above is $<1$. And because $n$ tends to $\infty$, and $n > 1 \rightarrow \sqrt[n]n > 1,$ the denominator is $>1$. Therefore the limit is $<1$ and the root test implies that $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ converges.

If there are any errors in my proof, I think they come from 1) my assumption of the converse of the root test theorem and 2) my misunderstanding of $\lim_{n\to\infty} sup$. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Well, you've _identified_ the error all by yourself! You say something about your _assumption_ of the converse of the root test. You know that when you're proving things you can't just _assume_ stuff. The converse of the root test is not true (at least your version of the converse). Think about the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality...

Comment: $\sum 1/n^2$ converges, but $\lim_n \root n\of {n^2}=1$. Instead, you could use the inequality $2ab\le (a^2+b^2)$ and the Comparison Test.

Comment: You're right, you can't assume the original limit is $< 1$, it could be $1$ (and yet you still have convergence) in which case your limit for the second series is also $1$ so you can't say anything about convergence using that test.

Comment: Your assumption of the converse i'snt right, the converse is \$\limsup_n \sqrt[n]{a_n} \leq 1$, you can use Cauchy-Schwarz to prove the convergence.

Comment: You do not have a proper understanding of $\limsup$. Please note that, among others, $\limsup \limits _n x_n \ne \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} (\sup x_n)$.

Comment: @AlexM. Actually, the OP explicitly noted his/her misunderstanding of the $\lim \sup$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: True. I just wanted to explicitly point out to him where he was mistaken. After all, I think that this was one of the points of his question, wasn't it?

Comment: @AlexM. Yes. He was requesting affirmation of areas of concern.   And you did affirm.

Comment: You are correct.  The converse of the root theorem requires the non-strict inequality.  That is, if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\lim \sup a_n^{1/n} \le 1$.  For example, $\sum n^{-2}$ converges, but $n^{-2/n}\to 1$.

Answer (score 2):

David Mitra basically spelled it out but in case you're unclear on the details, note $(a-b)^2 \geq 0$ gives you $ab \leq a^2/2 + b^2/2$. Then, set $a = \sqrt{a_n}$ and $b = 1/n$ and you will reduce proving convergence of your second series to simply proving that $\sum_n 1/n^2$ converges, for which you can use the Cauchy condensation test if you can't just assume convergence automatically for that series.

Comment: Thanks, that's a clever solution. Just out of curiosity, how do you and other people who answered find quick solutions like these? Have you seen the problem before, or does it just come with experience?

Comment: @agrasin It definitely helps to be familiar with things like Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. But one intuitive way to see this proof idea is to realize that a sum of two series is often much easier to analyze for convergence compared to a series where terms are products. So if you know the inequality, it is a natural thing to think of since it reduces convergence of the series of products to the convergence of two separate series, one of which you already know convergence as an assumption. The fact that the square in the inequality directly cancels the given square-root is just happy coincidence.